# Jquery append element with append doesn't apply to angular scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a page that can create a question so the student will answer it later. The thing is I start with 3 alternatives and it can grow to 5 alternatives

```
<textarea ng-model="question.text" rows="4" required></textarea>
<li class = "item1 alternativa">
            <input type="radio" name="question" id="answer1" value="0">
            <input ng-model="question.alternative0" maxlength = "50" autofocus = "autofocus" placeholder = "Digite a alternativa" class = "item1-textbox" />
            <span class = "icon-remove"title = "Remove item"></span>
        </li>
        <li class = "item2 alternativa">
            <input type="radio" name="question" id="answer2" value="1">
            <input ng-model="question.alternative1" maxlength = "50" autofocus = "autofocus" placeholder = "Digite a alternativa" class = "item2-textbox" />
            <span class = "icon-remove"title = "Remove item"></span>
        </li>
        <li class = "item3 alternativa">
            <input type="radio" name="question" id="answer3" value="2">
            <input ng-model="question.alternative2" maxlength = "50" autofocus = "autofocus" placeholder = "Digite a alternativa" class = "item3-textbox" />
            <span class = "icon-remove"title = "Remove item"></span>
        </li>
```

and then there's a jquery function to add/remove more alternatives:

```
  $(".add").click(function() {
  $("ul[class*='questions']").append("<li class = \'item" + count + "alternativa\'>" +
               "<input type='radio' name='question' value=\'" + count + "\' id = \'item" + count + "\' />" +
               "<label for = \'item " + count + " \' title = 'Mark Complete'></label>" +
               "<input ng-model=\question.alternative" + count + "\ maxlength = '50' autofocus = 'autofocus' \
                placeholder='Digite a Alternativa' class = \'item" + count + "-textbox\' />" +
               "<span class='icon-remove' title='Remove item'></span>" +
               "</li>");
```

So when I insert a new alternative i have a new input tag with the same structure as the first 3, however in my controller i can't reach them as they are printed as undefined

```
 $scope.question = {
      text: ""

}

  $scope.saveQuestion = function (question) {
    var videoId = $("#selectLesson").val();
    var questionment = question.text;
    console.log(question);
    var options = [question.alternative0,question.alternative1,question.alternative2,question.alternative3,question.alternative4];
    var answer = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
    console.log(options);
    console.log(questionment);
    $scope.esconderQuiz = false;
    //ConteudoService.saveQuestion(videoId,questionment,options,answer);
}
```

What can i do to have all the questions inside my question scope so I can pass it to my service?

edit: Having the 5 alternatives hidden is an option, however it doesn't look like a sophisticate resolution and could cause even more pain.

Comment: If you are using angular, there should not be a need to use jQuery. Use `ng-repeat` and on `add.click`, add element to list

Comment: You should not be manipulating DOM and listening to DOM events anywhere outside of directives when using AngularJS. That's one of the most important rules to understand. So `jQuery(...).on` like you are using it is a big no-no.

Comment: Doing the append function inside an angular function would do the trick?

Comment: I just moved my jquery code to angular controller, being called by ng-clicks, however it still doesn't get the values (printing undefined in my controller)

I think it has to do with the way Im calling the function in my html

<form id="form-quiz" ng-submit="saveQuestion(question)" class="animated fadeIn">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already commented:

> If you are using angular, there should not be a need to use jQuery. Use `ng-repeat` and on `add.click`, add element to list

Following is a simple representation of it. Also I have used `ng-show` to toggle visibility of questions. If you wish to change it, all you need to do is:

`$scope.questions[index].visible = true` or `$scope.questions[index].visible = true`

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.questions = [];
  var count = 0;
  for (count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    $scope.questions.push(new question(count));
  }
  
  $scope.add = function(){
    $scope.questions.push(new question(count++, true));
  }

  function question(index, visible) {
    this.title = "Question " + index;
    this.body = "abc def";
    this.answer = "answer";
    this.visible = visible?visible:index % 2 == 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="btn" ng-click="add()">+</div>
    <div ng-repeat="q in questions">
      <div ng-show="q.visible">
        <h3>{{q.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{q.body}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can really simplify this answer by staying away from JQuery and just use angular two-way binding and ng-repeats. This is an example I created to show how easily it can be done.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNJeJx

This allows you to add and remove questions and answers on the fly editing just the Javascript object and keeps all dom changes to the dom itself.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("Ctrl_List", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.newQuestion = {
        "q": "",
        "a": [""]
      }
      $scope.questions = [{
        "q": "Question One?",
        "a": [
          "AnsOne",
          "AnsTwo",
          "AnsThree"
        ]
      }, {
        "q": "Question Two?",
        "a": [
          "AnsOne",
          "AnsTwo"
        ]
      }, {
        "q": "Question Three?",
        "a": [
          "AnsOne",
          "AnsTwo",
          "AnsThree",
          "AnsFour"
        ]
      }];
      $scope.addQuestion = function() {
        alert("Added")
        $scope.questions.push($scope.newQuestion);
        $scope.newQuestion = {
          "q": "",
          "a": [""]
        }

      }
      $scope.addNewAnswer = function() {
        $scope.newQuestion.a.push("");
      }

    }
  ])
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="Ctrl_List">
    <h1>Questions</h1> Add New Question?
    <form>
      <input ng-model="newQuestion.q" placeholder="Question"></input>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Add Answer Field" ng-click="addNewAnswer()" />
      <br>
      <input ng-repeat="ans in newQuestion.a track by $index" placeholder="{{newQuestion.a[$index]}}" ng-model="newQuestion.a[$index]" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Add Question" ng-click="addQuestion()" />{{newQuestion}}
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <b>{{question.q}}</b>
      <br>
      <div ng-repeat="answer in question.a" ng-click="question.answer=$index">
        [ ] {{answer}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h1>Answers</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      {{$index}}) {{question.a[question.answer]}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**
Added adding a question method

Comment: The thing is I am creating the question, not loading them Dean Meehan. So its a single question with from 2 to 5 alternatives that can be changed in the view by the user

Comment: The example doesn't load any questions per say. There is nothing stopping you from creating the object manually to add the questions into the code. You could even add to the object from the dom, but this wouldn't save after reload... so not sure what the point would be.

Comment: The point was that i was not able to bind the alternatives created/ removed in the view since they lost binding to scope. The solution i found (bad one) was to load the values using javascript selectors and pass them to the Angular controller =/. Having the possibility from 2 to 5 alternatives broken my logic

Comment: I've created another example that allows to add questions. It allows any amount of questions or answers. I'm just trying to show it can be done simpler without the use of Jquery and ugly HTML pasting

Answer (score -1):

This is sort of the direction you want to go with this.  Create a directive and out everything in there.  Like this,

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    var questionDirective = function ($compile) {
        function controller() {

        }

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var listElement = $compile("<li class = \'item" + count + "alternativa\'>" +
                    "<input type='radio' name='question' value=\'" + count + "\' id = \'item" + count + "\' />" +
                    "<label for = \'item " + count + " \' title = 'Mark Complete'></label>" +
                    "<input ng-model=\question.alternative" + count + "\ maxlength = '50' autofocus = 'autofocus' \
                placeholder='Digite a Alternativa' class = \'item" + count + "-textbox\' />" +
                    "<span class='icon-remove' title='Remove item'></span>" +
                    "</li>");

            var $$addButton = element.find('.add'),
                    $$questionList = angular.element("ul[class*='questions']");

            $$addButton.on('click', function() {
                $$questionList.append(listElement);
            })
        }

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: link,
            controller: controller,
            templateUrl: 'questionDirective.html',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            bindToController: true,
            scope: {}
        };
    };

    angular.module('xapp')
            .directive('questionDirective', ['$compile', questionDirective]);
})(angular);
```

I am not completely sure how your whole html looks like, but you basically want to compile and then append to your template.  This way you have control over your content.  One other way to do this will be to have an array of object and then iterate there, and manipulate the object.

Comment: I dont know what here is worse - using $ in your variables, this template or using jquery selectors.

Comment: using $ in front of a variable has no affect really. it's a matter of style.